# NullPointerException in method

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I have a method that gets returns a type SENSOR 
In the bold is where I am getting a runtime NullPointerException, cannot understand why.

```
 public Sensor getSensorAt(int x,int y,GridMap grid)
      {
       /*go through sensor storage array 
       * for eachsensor index call the get x get y method for that 
       * compare it to the x,y of the robot 
       * 
       */  

        for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++){ 
             if(s1[i].getX() == x){    <======= NullpointerException
            if(s1[i].getY()== y){ 

            return s1[i]; 
            } 
          }      
        } 
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: Because something is `null`.  But it's impossible to say what, because you haven't shown us e.g. how `s1` is declared, initialised, etc.

Comment: s1[i] is null. Find out why it was not created where you expected it to be.

Answer (score 6):

You did not show us where `s1` is created, but it looks like `s1` does not have anything in it for some index `i`.

I tend to  write my for loops like so to make code like this a bit cleaner

```
Object result = null;
for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++){ 
    Object current = s1[i]; // Replace Object with whatever your array actually contains
    if(current.getX() == x && current.getY() == y) {
        result = current;
        break; // if you only need the first match
    }
}

return result;
```

Things like formatting are important and will help you prevent bugs in the first place, and make them easier to find when they do happen....

Comment: @Mjall2, thats great, but you should work on your code's formatting and clarity...

Answer (score 1):

Some of the elements in the array s1 is null, and when you are trying to invoke a method on that null object you are getting NPE.
Hope it helps you.